# Software for speeding up a video

Tags: video

I want to speed up a video clip in the order of 10x. However, I wasn't able to find a suitable software for that. I tried Movavi but the maximum speed up is 1000%. So I am not able to change the speed by 40x. Any recommendation for that?

Comment: What platform are you on? What’s your budget? Do you have any existing video software you would prefer to use?

Comment: I am using windows. A trial version is enough I think. If the software is good, I will go to the next steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) already? It's a very versatile command line tool.

Here is a [dedicated page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video) with a lot of examples on how to speed up/slow down a video with it.